# Display and Save Linked List of Objects

Tags: c++, linked-list, iterator

I have numerous functions written to implement on a linked list of objects. All I have left to write is the `display_list()` and the `save_to_file()` functions, which are proving to be quite difficult for me. I currently have the code for how it is done with strings instead of Passenger objects, but none of my conversions work. Below are only the relevant parts of the files.

**main.cc**

```
case 5: 
{
    display_list();
    break;
}

case 6: 
{
    save_to_file("ticket_reservations.dat");
    break;
}
```

**database.h**

```
include<list>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#ifndef passenger_h
#define passenger_h
 using std::string;
 using std::cin;
 using std::cout;
 using std::list;
 using std::endl;

class Passenger {
public:
    Passenger() {}
    Passenger(string, string, string);
    bool operator==(const Passenger&) const;
    bool operator<(const Passenger&) const;
private:
    string fname, lname, destination;

};

class Flightlist {
public:
    int menu();
    void read_from_file(string);
    void insert(Passenger p);
    void remove(Passenger p);
    bool check_reservation(Passenger p);
    void display_list();
    void save_to_file(string)
private:
    list<Passenger> flist;
};

#endif
```

**database.cc**

```
bool Flightlist::check_reservation(Passenger p)   //example of working function
{
    list<Passenger>::iterator i1, i2;
    i1 = flist.begin();
    i2 = flist.end();
    return flist.end() != find(flist.begin(), flist.end(), p);
}

void display_list()
{
    flist.sort();
    list<Passenger>::iterator i1, i2;
    i1 = flist.begin();
    i2 = flist.end();
    for ( ; i1 != i2; ++i1) {
        cout << *i1 << endl;
    }
}

void save_to_file(string filename)
{
    flist.sort();
    list<Passenger>::iterator i1, i2;
    i1 = flist.begin();
    i2 = flist.end();
    ofstream output(filename.c_str());
    for ( ; i1 != i2; ++i1) {
        output << *i1 << " ";
    }
    output.close();
}
```

The sort should take from the overloaded operators (== and <) so that they are sorted lexicographically on the last name.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: From what I see, you seem to be missing the overloaded `operator <<` to perform stream-insertion. Is that fundamentally what you're having problems with? For operator overload questions, I refer you to [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading), which you may find *very* helpful. Specifically, look for "Bitshift Operators (used for Stream I/O)" in the stellar selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool Flightlist::check_reservation(Passenger p);
```

The argument of `check_reservation` function should be passed by reference, or the assgin function of the `Passenger` class should be implemented, which is absent in it.

```
bool Flightlist::check_reservation(Passenger & p);
```

or:

```
class Passenger {
public:
    Passenger() {}
    Passenger(string, string, string);
    Passenger(const Passenger&);
    void operator=(const Passenger&) const;
    bool operator==(const Passenger&) const;

    bool operator<(const Passenger&) const;
private:
    string fname, lname, destination;

};
```

Comment: the check_reservation function is actually the only one that works there?

Comment: @Brittany Otherwise, just implement the object assignment function for Pasenger

Comment: I don't get what you mean? For the display_list and save_to_file classes?

Comment: @Brittany add assignment function and assignment constructor to the Passenger class.

Comment: @Brittany answer Updated

Comment: @lulyon `check_reservation` doesn't modify the parameter, and the search will invoke `operator ==`. There is no reason apart from efficiency to make that param a reference (and it would be `const` ideally at that), nor is there a need to overload the default assignment operator which will deep-copy this class just fine as-is. (and *neither* of those will address the OP's problem anyway). Finally, on what planet is an (unnecessary)  overloaded *assignment* operator `const` ?

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks for that, I was very confused as to why the only working function was the one being commented on  :/

Comment: @Brittany I urge you to check the link I provided up in general-comment. It covers a wide variety of topics about operator overloading, including what I think you seem to need: overloading stream-insertion, `std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream&, const Passenger&)`

Comment: @WhozCraig yes the "<< "  should be overloaded. But the OP's problem is with no speicific details, just guess.